# Ignore zooming & scrolling on some elements of UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, scroll

I want to be able to zoom in on and scroll an image but not have it affect buttons floating on top. Is this possible?

I've had success with scrolling and zooming by setting the html's viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.1, minimum-scale=1.1, maximum-scale=1.8, user-scalable=yes"/>
```